# Unable to pass an array to a function

Tags: solidity

I have this contract:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Ballot {
    constructor(string[] memory proposalNames) public {...}
}
```

I tried:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/voting.sol";

contract TestVoting {
    function testCounter() public {
        Ballot myContract = new Ballot(["foo", "bar"]);
    }
}
```

I got an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string memory[2] memory to string memory[] memory requested.
        Ballot myContract = new Ballot(["foo", "bar"]);
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
constructor(string[] memory proposalNames)
```

To this:

```
constructor(string[2] memory proposalNames)
```

Or this:

```
Ballot myContract = new Ballot(["foo", "bar"]);
```

To this:

```
string[] memory proposalNames = new string[](2);
proposalNames[0] = "foo";
proposalNames[1] = "bar";
Ballot myContract = new Ballot(proposalNames);
```